# Connecting Firebase to BigQuery Sandbox

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to connect Firebase to Google BigQuery Sandbox to check the raw data of Google Analytics for Firebase.

Linking Firebase and BigQuery needs to upgrade Firebase for Blaze plan. If I upgrade Blaze plan, is it not avaliable use BigQuery Sandbox?
If BigQuery Sandbox is not able to use Firebase Blaze plan, is it available BigQuery Free Trail?

I would like to know the combination to be able to Firebase Blaze plan connect to BigQuery.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a Programming forum. Which one is your programming question? You should ask in some other forum as [Super User](https://superuser.com/), f.e.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly for questions about billing and linking Firebase to Bigquery.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I understood. Asking firebase support directory.

Answer (score 1):

According to this Google Help's answer: [Link Firebase to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en).

> You can export Crashlytics, Predictions, Cloud Messaging, and
>   Performance Monitoring data to the BigQuery sandbox free of charge.
>   Data export for Google Analytics for Firebase is only available for
>   projects on the Blaze plan. With the full BigQuery integration
>   available on the Blaze plan, **you also gain access** to export data from
>   Google Analytics for Firebase

So you should be able to use BigQuery sandbox after upgrading to Blaze.